# Read configuration in to a collection of base class objects as child class objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, .net-core, configuration

I have .Net core application, which is using the appsettigs.json file for holding configuration. I need to load a configuration section into a collection, without iterating through them. I know I can use Bind() method to bind the collection into a collection of same type. But here I am trying to get objects of the child class type in the collection, instead of base class type.

```
"Sections": [
{
  "Name": "Section 1",
  "Type":"type1"

},
{
  "Name": "Section 2",
  "Type":"type2"

},
{
  "Name": "Section 3",
  "Type":"type1"

},
{
  "Name": "Section 4",
  "Type":"type1"

},
{
  "Name": "Section 5",
  "Type":"type2"

}]
```

I am using the below code to read the config file.

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
```

I know I can use Configuration.Bind()

The classes are

```
    Public abstract class BaseSection:ISection
    {
    public string Name;
    ..
    }


Public class Type1:BaseSection
{
public string Name;
..
}

Public class Type2:BaseSection
{
public string Name;
..
}
```

I need to read the configuration from the appsettings.json file to List such that the the for entry in config file with "type=type1" will have type in the collection Type1 obejct and "type=type2" will have type in the collection Type2 obejct.

So my collection from the above config entries should have

```
[
    Object Of Type1
    Object Of Type2
    Object Of Type1
    Object Of Type1
    Object Of Type2
]
```

I don't want to read the data once and then type cast it.

Please share views and inputs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intermediate list with binding, but you have to do some work to instanciate the right type. You can do something like that :

```
 namespace CoreApp1
 {
    public class ConfigSectionItem: BaseSection
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            var configuration = configBuilder.Build();
            var confList = new List<ConfigSectionItem>();

            configuration.GetSection("Sections").Bind(confList);

            foreach (var confItem in confList)
            {
                var typeToBuild = Type.GetType($"CoreApp1.{confItem.Type}"); // Remember to do some checks with typeToBuild (not null, ...)
                var newInstance = (BaseSection)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToBuild);

                newInstance.Name = confItem.Name; // Use automapper or reflexion

                // do what you want here with your newInstance
                Console.WriteLine(newInstance.GetType().FullName + " " + newInstance.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseSection
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    public class Type1 : BaseSection
    {
    }

    public class Type2 : BaseSection
    {
    }
 }
```

Be sure to use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
And please be carefull to case sensitive in .json or do some work to capitalize:

```
  "Type": "Type1"
  "Type": "Type2"
```